# how to implement implicit row level locking in innodb?

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions, locking, innodb

I'm using MySql(innodb storage engine). I want to implement row level implicit locking on update statement. so, that no other transaction can read or update that row concurrently.

Example: 
Transaction1 is executing
**"UPDATE Customers
SET City='Hamburg'
WHERE CustomerID=1;"**

Then, at same time Transaction2 should not able to read or update same row but Transaction2 should be able to access other rows.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: You only have one statement in there. InnoDB will automatically lock affected rows during the update. What do transactions have to do with this?

Comment: Useful: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking.html

Comment: Here transaction means  connection thread to database.

Comment: Can you @shmosel please explain, what will happen when multiple thread want to update same row concurrently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no other statements supporting that `UPDATE`, it is atomic.

If, for example, you needed to look at the row before deciding to change it, then it is a little more complex:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT ... FOR UPDATE;
decide what you need to do
UPDATE ...;
COMMIT;
```

No other connection can change with the row(s) `SELECTed` before the `COMMIT`.

Other connections can see the rows involved, but they may be seeing the values *before* the `BEGIN` started.  Reads usually don't matter.  What usually matters is that everything between `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` is "consistent", regardless of what is happening in other connections.

Your connection might be delayed, waiting for another connection to let go of something (such as the `SELECT...FOR UPDATE`).  Some other connection might be delayed.  Or there could be a "deadlock" -- when InnoDB decides that waiting will not work.

Comment: Thanks @Rick. But I want implement this lock implicitly on DB level, so that I don't need to begin transaction. On each update statement row should be locked irrespective of connections.

Comment: But why?  InnoDB's techniques are designed for efficiency; a big lock like you describe is wasteful.

Comment: @AanandKumar you seemd to have completely missed the 1st sentence of this answer.